# Remove comobox items between 2 indexs c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have a calendar application that allows the user to select two times (start time) and (end time) and assign specific events to certain users and saves it to a table in my Azure database

The user selects the times for the event using combo boxes. I am looking to remove all times that the user is busy from the combobox once a user already has an event taking place during that time so another user cannot overwrite their calendar.

I believe you could use some sort of iteration to accomplish this but I am uncertain on where to begin.

My code so far only removes the start time and end time of the event I would like to remove everything in between these two times as well.

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT StartTime,EndTime FROM Events WHERE AssignType='" + "Employee" + "' AND AssignTypeID='" + EmployeeID + "'", con);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                AssignTypeComboBox.Items.Remove(rdr["StartTime"].ToString());
                AssignTypeComboBox.Items.Remove(rdr["EndTime"].ToString());
            }
        }
```

This is the UI:

[image]

So say if I had an event scheduled for 3:00am-6:30am, everything in between should be removed from the Combobox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you're saying **remove**, but when did you **add** those items?

Comment: Why don't you convert the start time and end time into DateTime objects and remove everything in a loop.

Comment: You might be interested in a TimeComboBox I created a while back. Saw this post and updated the code to remove a range of time spans. Code is this [repository](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithTimeInVisualStudio).

Look at Form1, button labeled **Remove hours**.

Note the code provides just enough to see if this will work for you. Lastly not the time format is a tad different from yours e.g. 08:00 AM rather than 08:00am

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend do not mix DB reading and logic and UI.
Better to create separated class and methods Fill(start, end), Busy(start, end) and  Bind() at the end. In this case implementation will be much easy - just find all items between "busy" and remove. After it do binding.